# Java generics : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to K

Tags: java, generics

Following code is throwing compile time exception

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to K

What I understand is `K` should handle any value that extends `Number`.

```
public <K extends Number> K getValue(){
    Integer a = new Integer(1);
    return a;//Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to K
}
```

(Note: This is just a test code to put my question without giving irrelevant details of my actual scenario.)

Comment: The compiler is right. For example, at some point when you invoke this method, you will define the actual type of `K`, for example `K` could be defined as `Double`. In that case, K would not be an Integer and your code would be wrong. You're misunderstanding the meaning of "extends" here. In other words, you don't have any guarantee that because `K` extends Number, that K will be an Integer, it could a Double, or a Float or any other orthogonal type that extends number.

Comment: what if it would have been `<K extends Integer>`. It will still give me same warning message.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) will maybe help understand things better.

Comment: You bring an interesting point. The expectation would be that since `K` is a type that extends `Integer` that the compiler would know you can assign an `Integer` to `K` (i.e. `K k = new Integer(10)`. However that seems not to be the case. For all that matters, the compiler expects `K` to be bound to some type that extends Integer at some point and it will enforce that constraint, but `K` is not Integer, instead `K` is a type on its own and it seems the compiler makes no polymorphic inferences about it. I suppose a cast could be forced (i.e. `(K) new Integer(10)`.

Comment: To put it another way: the type parameter `<K extends SomeType>` does not mean "any type that extends `SomeType`", but rather "a single, specific, but yet unknown subtype of `SomeType`". From this it's also easy to see why it doesn't make sense to use this as purely a return type of a method. If you just want to say "this method can return any subtype of `Number`", you don't need type parameters at all: `public Number getNumber()` already does that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is the fact that `K` is a type that extends `Number` but it is an **unknown** sub class of `Number` that is why the compiler raises this error because `Integer` is only one specific sub class of `Number` so it cannot match with any potential target types.

Let's say that you want to cast it explicitly to make it compile with

```
public <K extends Number> K getValue(){
    Integer a = new Integer(1);
    return (K) a;
}
```

Then if you call it expecting any sub class of `Number` except `Integer` you will get a `ClassCastException`, that is exactly what the compiler wants to avoid:

```
Double d = getValue(); <-- throws ClassCastException
```

As workaround you could define your method using `Number` as returned type as next:

```
public Number getValue() {
    return new Integer(1);
}
```

Comment: so does it mean that `extends` should not be part of return type if its not collection? and use Superclass instead.

Comment: in this case, yes I believe so

Comment: I agree with @biziclop, in summary `extends` should be used in case of collections but for normal assignment and return types use `SuperClass`.