# What is wrong with the following generics code?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method declared as below

```
public static <E extends Number> List<E> myListOfElements(List<E> list) {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

What I understand from this is it's expecting a List of type which extends `Number` as input and List of type which extends `Number` as output. When I try to return an `ArrayList<Integer>`r it gives a compilation error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Integer> to List<E>
```

I don't understand what is the problem here. Why can't I return an `ArrayList<Integer>` here?

Comment: Did you import the right `List` (`java.util.List`)?

Comment: The type variable `E` is universally quantified. This means that a method that implements that type signature must be able to return a `List<E>` *for all* `E` extending `Number`, not merely for `E = Integer`.

Comment: FYI: Anything that looks like XML (i.e. `<Integer>`) must be code-formatted (surrounded by back-ticks or the entire block indented 4 spaces,  or it will get swallowed by Markdown processing.

Comment: You're returning an `ArrayList<Integer>`, but you could invoke this with `List<Double> list = myListOfElements(Arrays.asList(0.0));`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin If you expand on your comment a little you have a good answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this dupe is relevant, but not directly: OP isn't trying to assign a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>`, but rather a `List<Integer>` to a `List<AnySubtypeOfNumber>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yah, I may have jumped the gun with that dupe. Do you have a better suggestion for a dupe or should I reopen?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809872/java-generics-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-integer-to-k) is likely better. Sorry.

Comment: @Logan You don't need to apologize for anything.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well I jumped the gun a bit there with the suggested dupe, haha.

Comment: @AndyTurner If we cast it to `(List<E>)` in the method, why doesn't the typecast fail in that method? Example: If I do `List<Double> myD = myListOfElements(new ArrayList<Double>());` and the method actually retunrs `new ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: @user7 Can you show a complete example? You can link to http://repl.it or some similar site.

Comment: @user7 "why doesn't the typecast fail in that method" What do you mean? Are you asking why you can write that code in the first place?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Here it is https://ideone.com/G37mYP

Comment: @AndyTurner Please refer to the ideone link for the sample code

Comment: Has it to do with the *unchecked cast*

Comment: @AndyTurner In `myListOfElements(new ArrayList<Integer>());` `E` gets inferred as `Integer` - then in the method aren't we casting `ArrayList<Double>` to `List<Integer>`?

Comment: @user7 yes, the unchecked cast is relevant. That's saying that the cast isn't actually a cast in the compiled code, so it doesn't fail at that point, but rather later, when you attempt to use the element as an `Integer`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I guess with cast we get away at compile time. At runtime due to type erasure, everything is a just a raw type List - so failure happens only we retrieve from list. Am I right?

Comment: @user7 By explicitly casting in `return (List<E>) i;`, you are telling the compiler that you think you know what you are doing. Without that cast, you should get a similar error to the one asked about here.

Comment: Something like [this](https://repl.it/@codeguru/UnfoldedDodgerblueCable) will compile, but I don't think it enforces that the two captured types are the same.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the inputs.